# Android Studio Binding error Cannot resolve method

Tags: android, android-studio, android-databinding

Android Studio 3.1.3 informs that cannot resolve method error while trying call Data Binding method. Data binding is enabled in `build.gradle`. Clear and/or Rebuild project takes no effect. Only one thing helps — restarting Android Studio. Any suggestions?

An interesting moment is that Studio can build and run the app, inspite of the data binding error.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to this is known bug of AS. You can solve this by the following:

1. Rename corresponding layout file (Ctrl+F6)
2. Run Rebuild project (errors will shown as a result)
3. Rename the layout back to original name

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

> When you build and deploy to your device, Data Binding will generate
>   an associated class with a similar name, just in CamelCase:
>   ListItemCrimeBinding.
>
> Unlike generated code tools like Dagger, Data Binding does not rely on
>   generated code for type checking. Instead, it is integrated into
>   Android Studio, so that you do not have to wait through a whole code
>   generation pass to use the fields and methods Data Binding provides.
>
> As of this writing, this integration needs a little jump-start to get
>   going. To make ListItemCrimeBinding available after adding the
>    tag, you must restart Android Studio, then rebuild the
>   project.

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/descent-into-databinding/.

Comment: Before the last update of Android Studio I did not have to restart it